# Find the interval for whch the function is increasing and decreasing

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ g(x)=\int_{-10}^{x} tf'(t)dt   $$  for $x\geq -10$,

Where $f$ is an increasing function.Then in which interval $g(x)$ *increases and decreases.*

Comment: yes after that I am stuck when it comes to increasing decreasing

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla You mean $g^{\color{red}{´}}(x)=xf^´(x)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$g'(x) = x f'(x), \,\,\,\,\,\,\, x \ge -10.$$ Since $f$ is increasing, we have $f'(x) \ge 0$, so $g'(x) \ge 0$ when $x \ge 0$ and $g'(x) \le 0$ when $x<0$. Hence $g$ is increasing when $x \ge 0$ and $g$ is decreasing when $x < 0$.

Comment: I would edit that equal sign though. When $x=0$ it is neither increasing not decreasing.